# Specifying a scene in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, scenekit, scene

I'm trying to render a scene created in Blender. I don't want to do this in code, but solely in Interface Builder.

Firstly I added a SceneKit framework in Linked Frameworks and Libraries under General tab, than I copied the .dae, dragged a SCNView into a View and in the Attributes Inspector changed Scene to the name of my .dae file. For some reason, the simulator is completely green (background color of SCNView) and does not render my scene from .dae file. The same procedure works on macOS application.

This is a screenshot of my setup:[image]

Comment: do you see any error or warning in the console when you run the app?

Comment: nope, not a single complaint

Comment: which version of Xcode are you using? Xcode 6 or Xcode 7?

Comment: Xcode 6. Moustach confirmed it is a bug.

Comment: which is fixed in Xcode 7 :)

Comment: I guess it's time to update the xcode :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on this a few months ago and [posted my results here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28771252/2053038)

It is a problem in Scenekit, probably something not getting loaded properly. I filled a bug report to Apple and a few days ago I got confirmation of the problem, and the info that it should be fixed in the next version of Xcode.